# List of European banks by assets and/or deposits

Tags: finance, banks, banking-regulations, central-banking, banking

Does anyone know where I can find a list of European commercial banks that includes assets and/or deposits?

I found this link on ECB's website:

https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/financial_corporations/list_of_financial_institutions/html/elegass.en.html

It lists the banks that I need, however only reference information such as name, address and country.

Comment: My first thought is that no one will have pre compiled this list for you and made it publicly available. My first attempt to do this would be as follows: 1) convert the list of institutions to a Bloomberg recognizable identifier. 2) Ask bloomberg help or a command to extract balance sheet total assets and liabilities given an identifier.

Comment: Doesn't Bloomberg have information only on banks listed in the stock market? There are 6000+ banks in Europe, many of them are small and probably not in Bloomberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECB can get you Eurosystem-wide aggregates, but remember that these are just reported by the ECB by the national central banks, who actually regulate the banks. The rules and reporting standards are Europe-wide; but this is nationally operated. And the precise figures for every individual bank are commercially-sensitive data. I'm not sure they are a matter of public record for a small privately-owned institution; even if the national regulators have the right to know.

You can probably find this out for the so-called SIFI and G-SIFI banks (ie the too big to fail crowd), if only because they are frequently stress-tested and the results of those exercises are a matter of public record (justified on grounds of market and public confidence in the central banks' financial stability remit). That's all well and good for the ~20 biggest banks; but omits the long-tail of the 1000s of smaller banks.

But then you have to be careful about exactly what you're looking at. The likes of BNP or DBK are regulated globally by their national CB, including on assets/deposits outside the Eurosystem. Likewise most figures from journalism, sellside research etc. will capture a group-wide balance sheet (that includes a lot of financial services but not commercial banking operations). But the ECB figures will only reflect the Eurozone component of their European commercial banking divisions. So you're looking at multiple potential answers to different question that won't reconcile with each other.

Short answer - it doesn't exist, to my knowledge, line-by-line... however, the EZ aggregates offer a fair reflection on the pace of deleveraging, capital raising etc.

Comment: In the US this information is accessible quarterly on the FDIC website, including assets and deposits of small banks. Why Europe is different?

Comment: Fair question, and please don't shoot messenger. I can only observe that the ECB only got financial stability oversight over EZ banks - and against their wishes (given the conflicts that then arise) a couple of years ago, as an emergency measure to stop the then-toxic bank-sovereign spiral of death killing the Euro. "European Banking Union" remains a promised objective, still actually far from being delivered in any meaningful sense.

Comment: Plus small but important point. Germany has probably the best industrial productivity on the planet, with also probably the crappest banking system (in the absence of other macro problems). Normally, Europe is a core-periphery problem of some kind. With banking, the normally Puritan Germans actually resist transparency. The real problem: the banks that used to finance their industrial miracle, and now embarrass so don't talk about them, are publically-owned "Landesbank". Best swept under carpet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of stats is published by the European Banking Authority, (EBA)  for example https://eba.europa.eu/-/the-eba-updates-data-used-for-the-identification-of-global-systemically-important-institutions-g-sii-2 .

Comment: I'm interested in all the banks, mainly the small ones - that may not be systemically important therefore not in the list